# How can i keep my App on Canvas page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

I can't find i smooth 100% working way to keep my app in the canvas at all times, When Facebook publish actions and stream it will link to the website url and not to the canvas.

How can this be solved in a smooth way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  if (parent.location.href == self.location.href) {

        window.location.href = "https://apps.facebook.com/APP

   <?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];?>";
    }

  </script>
```